# how to test a database inside a docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, redis, jmeter, ignite

I want to test the MongoDB database and the In-Memory Database Redis and Apache ignite in displaying data, to see the performance of the 3 databases in the hope that I can find out the Throughput, Latency, Resource utilization and Error Rate values of these databases in displaying data.

to do this test I plan to use the jmeter extension on the Docker Desktop.

therefore please give me the steps and what to do to do this test using the jmeter extension in the docker desktop application or do I have to add a jmeter image to my docker-compose.yml

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.  [ask] in the SO Help Center may be a useful guide to you: this question doesn't obviously seem to be programming-related, and questions tend to be better-received if you describe what you've done so far and a specific problem than just naming a tool and a goal.